# Printing table with different number of enteries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns - name and number. I would like to group all the names based on the number column and then print the data in a table format with all the names with the number 1 and next to them the names with number 2 and so on.
For example,
if input is:

```
name = ['Bob','David','Jane','Mike','Josh','Emily']
number = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
df = pd.DataFrame([name,number]).T
df.columns = ['name','number']
```

Desired output (but hopefully looks much better):

```
num1     num2  num3

Bob          David     Jane

Mike         Josh      

Emily
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `groupby`, group on `number`, convert to a dictionary, and re-create your dataframe.

```
d = df.groupby('number').name.apply(list).to_dict()

df = pd.DataFrame({k : pd.Series(v) 
       for k, v in d.items()}).add_prefix('num').fillna('')

print(df)
    num1   num2  num3
0    Bob  David  Jane
1   Mike   Josh      
2  Emily
```

Comment: Can you confirm that my second option works?  Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared sure, will do it when I’m back on my PC, if you haven’t already done it by then!

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
f = 'num{}'.format

for nm, nb in zip(df.name, df.number):
    d[f(nb)].append(nm)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T.fillna('')

    num1   num2  num3
0    Bob  David  Jane
1   Mike   Josh      
2  Emily
```

---

**Option 2**

```
i = df.groupby('number').cumcount().values
j, c = pd.factorize(df.number.values)

a = np.empty((i.max() + 1, c.size), dtype='<U32')
a.fill('')
a[i, j] = df.name.values

pd.DataFrame(a, columns=c).add_prefix('num')

    num1   num2  num3
0    Bob  David  Jane
1   Mike   Josh      
2  Emily
```

Comment: Unfortunately second return `a[i, j] = df.name.values` -> `[['B' 'D' 'J']
 ['M' 'J' '']
 ['E' '' '']]`, so output is `num1 num2 num3
0    B    D    J
1    M    J     
2    E `

Comment: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 4), indices imply (3, 4)` on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df.groupby('number').cumcount(),'number'])['name']
        .unstack(fill_value='')
        .add_prefix('num')
        .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df1)
    num1   num2  num3
0    Bob  David  Jane
1   Mike   Josh      
2  Emily
```

Alternative with `Series` of `list`s:

```
a = df.groupby('number')['name'].apply(list)
a.index.name = None
print (a)
1    [Bob, Mike, Emily]
2         [David, Josh]
3                [Jane]
Name: name, dtype: object

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist(), index=a.index).T.add_prefix('num').fillna('')
print (df1)
    num1   num2  num3
0    Bob  David  Jane
1   Mike   Josh      
2  Emily
```